# Clojure reduce/count the number of elements in a collection

Tags: clojure

I have this function:

```
(defn movies [directors]
  (->> directors
       (mapcat :movies)
       (group-by :genre)))
```

which gives me this output:

```
{"Action" [{:title "Blade Runner 2049", :genre "Action", :year 2017}],
 "Drama"
 [{:title "Gladiator", :genre "Drama", :year 2000}
  {:title "Apocalypse Now", :genre "Drama", :year 1979}
  {:title "The Departed", :genre "Drama", :year 2006}
  {:title "The Aviator", :genre "Drama", :year 2004}],
 "Adventure" [{:title "Mars", :genre "Adventure", :year 2015}],
 "Crime"
 [{:title "American Gangster", :genre "Crime", :year 2007}
  {:title "The Godfather", :genre "Crime", :year 1972}
  {:title "GoodFellas", :genre "Crime", :year 1990}],
 "Comedy"
 [{:title "Jack", :genre "Comedy", :year 1996}
  {:title "The Wolf", :genre "Comedy", :year 2013}]}
```

I would like to count the number of movies in every category using reduce or count in the same function "movies"

Thanks,
R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(frequencies 
 (sequence (comp (mapcat :movies)
                 (map :genre)) 
           directors))
```

Answer (score 1):

This works by just counting the number in each `:genre` group:

```
(map #((juxt key (comp count val)) %) your-current-output)
;; => (["Action" 1] ["Drama" 4] ["Adventure" 1] ["Crime" 3] ["Comedy" 2])
```

So for your function:

```
(defn movies [directors]
  (->> directors
       (mapcat :movies)
       (group-by :genre)
       (map #((juxt key (comp count val)) %))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use `reduce` there? Because you can count items using the combination of `map` and `frequencies`:

```
(defn movies [directors]
  (->> directors
       (mapcat :movies)
       (map :genre)
       frequencies)
```

Comment: Hi Oleg, using it like that it gives me always 1, which is the number : {["Action" [{:title "Blade Runner 2049", :genre "Action", :year 2017}]]
 1,
 ["Drama"
  [{:title "Gladiator", :genre "Drama", :year 2000}
   {:title "Apocalypse Now", :genre "Drama", :year 1979}
   {:title "The Departed", :genre "Drama", :year 2006}
   {:title "The Aviator", :genre "Drama", :year 2004}]]
 1,

Comment: @razvan, it seems that you're still grouping movies by genre. You need to remove call to `group-by` (as in my example)